# create mongo db collections at once from an api call or any other method?

Tags: mongodb

I'm creating an app from nextjs. what i need to do is, i want to create all collections at once using an api or any other method.

example :- lets say i have user collection / test1 collection / test3 collection, what i need is create this at once. so i dont need to make test collection table and when user register api is called.

i need few suggextions. i dont need to create an collection after login api is called. what i need is to create all the collections before app is loaded